arrange values and labels on plots xticks
plt.plot(neighbors, train_scores, label="Train Score")
plt.plot(neighbors, test_scores, label="Test Score")
plt.xticks(np.arange(1,21,1))
plt.xlabel("Number of Neighbors")
plt.ylabel("Score")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

`print(f"Maximum KNN score on the test data is: {max(test_scores)*100:.2f}%")`

it gives me a Type error
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[62], line 5
      3 plt.plot(neighbors, train_scores, label="Train Score")
      4 plt.plot(neighbors, test_scores, label="Test Score")
----> 5 plt.xticks(np.arange(1,21,1))
      6 plt.xlabel("Number of Neighbors")
      7 plt.ylabel("Score")

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
I tried looking if mistakly i have use x_ticks as s varialble but it is not the case

From the example on xticks on the matplotlib site try the following:
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 21, step=1)) 


How about:
tick = np.arange(1,21,1)
plt.xticks(tick)

or use "#" to comment that line and see the raw figure first.
